# Multivariate mapping / regression with objective function

Tags: statistics, neural-network, regression, svm

**Overview**
I have a multivariate timeseries of "inputs" of dimension N that I want to map to an output timeseries of dimension M, where M < N.  The inputs are bounded in [0,k] and the outputs are in [0,1].  Let's call the input vector for some time slice in the series "**I[t]**" and the output vector "**O[t]**".

Now if I knew the optimal mapping of pairs **<I[t], O[t]>**, I could use one of the standard multivariate regression / training techniques (such as NN, SVM, etc) to discover a mapping function.

**Problem**
I do not know the relationship between specific **<I[t], O[t]>** pairs, rather have a view on the overall fitness of the output timeseries, i.e. the fitness is governed by a penalty function on the complete output series.

I want to determine the mapping / regressing function "**f**", where:

```
     O[t] = f (theta, I[t])
```

Such that penalty function P(O) is minimized:

```
     minarg P( f(theta, I) )
       theta
```

[Note that the penalty function P is being applied the resultant series generated from multiple applications of **f** to the **I[t]**'s across time.  That is **f** is a function of **I[t]** and not the whole timeseries]

The mapping between I and O is complex enough that I do not know what functions should form its basis.  Therefore expect to have to experiment with a number of basis functions.

Have a view on one way to approach this, but do not want to bias the proposals.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

... depends on your definition of *optimal mapping* and *penalty function*. I'm not sure if this is the direction you're taking, but here's a couple of suggestions:

- For example you can find a mapping of the data from the higher dimensional space to a lower dimension space that tries to preserve the original *similarity* between data points (something like **Multidimensional Scaling [MDS]**).
- Or you can prefer to map the data to a lower dimension that accounts for as much of the *variability* in the data as possible (**Principal Component Analysis [PCA]**).